# How to find the best function which interpolates a set of data?

Tags: interpolation

I have a set of data as follows:

```
dataset={{-9.21034037198, 0., -0.141337}, {-6.90775527898, 
  0., -0.140006}, {-4.60517018599, 0., -0.128294}, {-2.30258509299, 
  0., -0.08616}, {0., 0., -0.060066}, {2.30258509299, 
  0., -0.052768}, {4.60517018599, 0., -0.05065}, {6.90775527898, 
  0., -0.049998}, {9.21034037198, 0., -0.049804}, {-9.21034037198, 
  0.405465108108, -0.168189}, {-6.90775527898, 
  0.405465108108, -0.166854}, {-4.60517018599, 
  0.405465108108, -0.15485}, {-2.30258509299, 
  0.405465108108, -0.106014}, {0., 
  0.405465108108, -0.071659}, {2.30258509299, 
  0.405465108108, -0.061878}, {4.60517018599, 
  0.405465108108, -0.059054}, {6.90775527898, 
  0.405465108108, -0.058182}, {9.21034037198, 
  0.405465108108, -0.05801}, {-9.21034037198, 
  0.69314718056, -0.183855}, {-6.90775527898, 
  0.69314718056, -0.182519}, {-4.60517018599, 
  0.69314718056, -0.170363}, {-2.30258509299, 
  0.69314718056, -0.117372}, {0., 
  0.69314718056, -0.077021}, {2.30258509299, 
  0.69314718056, -0.065352}, {4.60517018599, 
  0.69314718056, -0.061987}, {6.90775527898, 
  0.69314718056, -0.060948}, {9.21034037198, 
  0.69314718056, -0.060632}, {-9.21034037198, 
  1.09861228867, -0.199277}, {-6.90775527898, 
  1.09861228867, -0.197939}, {-4.60517018599, 
  1.09861228867, -0.185627}, {-2.30258509299, 
  1.09861228867, -0.127794}, {0., 
  1.09861228867, -0.079589}, {2.30258509299, 
  1.09861228867, -0.065423}, {4.60517018599, 
  1.09861228867, -0.061356}, {6.90775527898, 
  1.09861228867, -0.060105}, {9.21034037198, 
  1.09861228867, -0.059732}, {-9.21034037198, 
  2.30258509299, -0.197347}, {-6.90775527898, 
  2.30258509299, -0.196007}, {-4.60517018599, 
  2.30258509299, -0.183502}, {-2.30258509299, 
  2.30258509299, -0.118805}, {0., 
  2.30258509299, -0.059557}, {2.30258509299, 
  2.30258509299, -0.043268}, {4.60517018599, 
  2.30258509299, -0.038901}, {6.90775527898, 
  2.30258509299, -0.037607}, {9.21034037198, 
  2.30258509299, -0.037289}, {-9.21034037198, 
  3.91202300543, -0.136159}, {-6.90775527898, 
  3.91202300543, -0.134821}, {-4.60517018599, 
  3.91202300543, -0.12246}, {-2.30258509299, 
  3.91202300543, -0.064103}, {0., 
  3.91202300543, -0.022337}, {2.30258509299, 
  3.91202300543, -0.013917}, {4.60517018599, 
  3.91202300543, -0.011953}, {6.90775527898, 
  3.91202300543, -0.011385}, {9.21034037198, 
  3.91202300543, -0.011227}, {-9.21034037198, 
  5.33271879327, -0.08276}, {-6.90775527898, 
  5.33271879327, -0.081427}, {-4.60517018599, 
  5.33271879327, -0.06956}, {-2.30258509299, 
  5.33271879327, -0.026594}, {0., 
  5.33271879327, -0.006969}, {2.30258509299, 
  5.33271879327, -0.004001}, {4.60517018599, 
  5.33271879327, -0.003363}, {6.90775527898, 
  5.33271879327, -0.003177}, {9.21034037198, 
  5.33271879327, -0.003137}, {-9.21034037198, 
  5.99146454711, -0.063705}, {-6.90775527898, 
  5.99146454711, -0.062375}, {-4.60517018599, 
  5.99146454711, -0.050894}, {-2.30258509299, 
  5.99146454711, -0.016263}, {0., 
  5.99146454711, -0.00386}, {2.30258509299, 
  5.99146454711, -0.002165}, {4.60517018599, 
  5.99146454711, -0.001811}, {6.90775527898, 
  5.99146454711, -0.001702}, {9.21034037198, 
  5.99146454711, -0.001838}, {-9.21034037198, 
  6.80239476332, -0.04532}, {-6.90775527898, 
  6.80239476332, -0.043998}, {-4.60517018599, 
  6.80239476332, -0.03318}, {-2.30258509299, 
  6.80239476332, -0.008381}, {0., 
  6.80239476332, -0.001815}, {2.30258509299, 
  6.80239476332, -0.000999}, {4.60517018599, 
  6.80239476332, -0.000835}, {6.90775527898, 
  6.80239476332, -0.000777}, {9.21034037198, 
  6.80239476332, -0.000907}, {-9.21034037198, 
  7.51534457118, -0.033161}, {-6.90775527898, 
  7.51534457118, -0.031848}, {-4.60517018599, 
  7.51534457118, -0.021825}, {-2.30258509299, 
  7.51534457118, -0.004495}, {0., 
  7.51534457118, -0.000921}, {2.30258509299, 
  7.51534457118, -0.000501}, {4.60517018599, 
  7.51534457118, -0.000422}, {6.90775527898, 
  7.51534457118, -0.000385}, {9.21034037198, 
  7.51534457118, -0.000527}}
```

where the structure of each inner list is `{x,y,f(x,y)}` which x has an approximate range of -9 to 9 and y has 0 to 7.  I want to find the best function in term of x  and y. I looked for such a command in Mathematica and found `FindFormula` but it doesn't work for my dataset. Also I saw commands such as `Interpolation`, `ListInterpolation` and `InterpolatingFunction` but all of them generate a numerical approximation as I understood. How can I find the best function or formula which simulates my dataset as good as possible?

**Addendum**

I look for a simple and compact function which reproduces my data. By compact and simple I mean a well-known mathematical function (or mix of a few) which can reproduces my dataset. For example I had tried a procedure for another similar dataset. In that case I found a function which could take x and give f(x,y), then I tried to add a dependency to y to initial function. In fact I did a two-step fitting, So first I found a Logistic function and then reproduced its parameters using a Morse function. Namely I had a few parameters (maybe 5 or 6), not 30 or 40 parameters as the following answers But this time I wanted to do all works in one step as I said in my question.

Comment: Look at the data with ListPointPlot3D and guess. Otherwise you're asking for symbolic regression which is a hard problem but has been mentioned here before. Ultimately you're always doing some kind of numerical approximation / parameter estimation and it's unlikely you'll find an exact formula for all but the simplest data sets.

Comment: @flinty so how `FindFormula` works? Is not it appropriate for my case?

Comment: First you have to define which functions are acceptable. E.g. Polynomials of degree <20. Then you have to define what you mean by "best". E.g. "least square". Only then can you compute the "best" function.

Comment: @DanielHuber for which command? can you bring me an example?

Comment: [`InterpolatingPolynomial`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingPolynomial.html) will provide an explicit polynomial; however, it has large oscillations in `x`

Answer (score 5):

To give an example a comment has not enough space. Here is an explicite example for your data.

For simplicity I will choose "least square" as a criterion for goodness. But you could as well use a "MinMax" where the maximal error is minimized or some other criterion.

First we will need a basis of functions. Again for simplicity I choose polynomials:

```
nx = 5; ny = 5;
base = Table[x^i y^j, {i, 0, nx}, {j, 0, ny}] // Flatten;
```

You may play with nx and ny to get better or worse fits. Conveniently a function for least square fitting is already built into MMA:

```
fit = Fit[dataset, base, {x, y}];
```

We may plot the fitted surface together with the original points:

```
Show[{
  Plot3D[fit, {x, -9, 9}, {y, 0, 7}],
  Graphics3D[{Red, Point@d}]
  }]
```

[image]

Or we may plot the errors as lines above/below the fitted surface:

```
Show[{
  Plot3D[fit, {x, -9, 9}, {y, 0, 7}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "f(x,y)"}],
  Graphics3D[{Green, Thickness[0.008], 
    Line[{{#[[1]], #[[2]], fit /. {x -> #[[1]], y -> #[[2]]}}, #}] & /@
      dataset}]
  }]
```

[image]

As you can see, the errors are pretty small for our small base.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer, however it's not my desire one, because I need an analytic function, namely a compact and simple form. Beside relative high accuracy, the final form of suggested function is very important for me. Otherwise I know Mathematica can fit my data to a long polynomial for example. Anyway Thanks again.

Comment: You will need to define what "compact and simple" means. Then you need to define a base from "simple" function and fit this base to the data. Try e.g. polynomials of low degree. Or try circular function like Sin and Cos.  They all define complete families of functions.  Or do you have any preference for special functions from theory?

Comment: Please see the addendum

Answer (score 3):

I think there are two possible answers here. Answer 1 assumes your data is perfect and you just wish to interpolate it to give a function that can be used like any analytic function.  Answer 2 assumes you have errors in your data and you need a least squares fit through the data with a smooth function.

**Answer 1**

Just interpolate the data.

```
{xmin, xmax} = MinMax[dataset[[All, 1]]];
{ymin, ymax} = MinMax[dataset[[All, 2]]];
int = Interpolation[dataset];
Show[
 Plot3D[int[x, y], {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}],
 Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[dataset]}]
 ]
```

[image]

The interpolation function goes through every point and you can work with in-between points by just writing, for example

```
int[0.1, 2.5]

-0.0536997
```

**Answer 2**

We now assume that there are errors in your data so we have to do some least -squares fitting before finding an interpolation function that is best for your data.

First we form some control points. These can be unevenly spaced but for simplicity I choose equally spaced points. You can choose as many points as you like as long as they are fewer than the number of data points.

```
nx = 4; (* Number of control points in x direction *)
ny = 4;  (* Number of control points in y direction *)
xx = Table[xmin + (x - xmin), {x, xmin, xmax, (xmax - xmin)/(nx - 1)}];
yy = Table[ymin + (y - ymin), {y, ymin, ymax, (ymax - ymin)/(ny - 1)}];
```

Now we define a symbolic interpolation function where the ordinates are unknown values.

```
ClearAll[f];
pts = Flatten[Table[{{x, y}, f[x, y]}, {x, xx}, {y, yy}], 1];
sint = Interpolation[pts];
```

We now identify the unknowns and then set up equations using the data set and the symbolic interpolation function. We then form a least squares solution for the unknowns and put those into the symbolic interpolation function to give a best fit interpolation function.

```
uk = pts[[All, 2]];
eqns = Table[{x, y, z} = dataset[[n]]; 
   z == sint[x, y], {n, Length@dataset}];
{rhs, mat} = CoefficientArrays[eqns, uk];
vals = LeastSquares[mat, -rhs];
int = sint /. Thread[uk -> vals];
```

This new interpolation function is a best fit to your data. We can plot the fitted interpolation function and your data to see the errors.

```
Show[
 Plot3D[int[x, y], {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}],
 Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[dataset]}]
 ]
```

[image]

As expected the interpolation function does not go through the data points but is a best fit to them.

Hope that helps. Which answer are you after?

Comment: Many Thanks. Unfortunately all two answers are not my desire one. I look for an analytic function (compact and simple) which can reproduces my dataset in the best possible way. Notice I don't want to sacrifice simplicity of function for its accuracy. Also your first answer doesn't give an analytic form.

Comment: Why do you think there is a simple analytic function for your data? If you use splines (interpolation functions) then you are representing your data by several different  polynomials all joined together. This is the standard way of getting an analytic function for data. You can take derivatives and integrate and manipulate as needed. It is unlikely that there is a simple [elementary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) to represent your data.

Comment: Please see the addendum

Comment: Good luck. There is no reason why there should be a simple function.

Comment: Thanks bro. In fact I need a compact function which can be presented as an analytic solution